# Django Rest Framework Error: JSON parse error - Expecting ':' delimiter: line 4 column 21 (char 103)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to save a new user via POST request using the @api_view decorator in DRF but got the following error :

```
{
    "detail": "JSON parse error - Expecting ':' delimiter: line 4 column 21 (char 103)"
}
```

**models.py code:**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from PIL import Image
from django.conf import settings

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default = 'users/default.jpg', upload_to = 'users/profile_pics')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

    def save(self,  **kwargs):
        super().save()
        img = Image.open(self.image.path)
        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300, 300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)
```

**views.py code:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
from .serializers import UserSerializer
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status

@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def user_list(request):

    if request.method == 'GET':
        users = User.objects.all().order_by('id')
        serializer = UserSerializer(users, many = True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = UserSerializer(data = request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status = status.HTTP_201_created)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**serializers.py code:**

```
from rest_framework import serializer
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Profile
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only = True)
    password = serializers.CharField(
        required = False,
        write_only = True,
        style = {"input_type": "password", "placeholder": "Password"}
    )
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', 'username', 'email', 'password']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        validated_data['password'] = make_password(validated_data.get('password'))
        return super(UserSerializer, self).create(validated_data)
```

**urls.py code:**

```
from django.urls import path, include
from .views import user_list, user_detail
from rest_framework import routers


urlpatterns = [
    path('users/', user_list),
    path('users/<int:pk>/', user_detail),
]
```

I am learning DRF from scratch and am following the documentation accordingly. I am not sure why I am getting the HTTP 400 Bad Request error here. It would be great if anyone can help me out.

This is an example of my POST request:

```
{
    "username": "user_1",
    "email": "user1m@gmail.com",
    "password" : "testing1234"
}
```

ID is auto-incremented and a password is required (as mentioned in the serializer.py code)

Comment: how does JSON you are trying to send looks like

Comment: @iklinac please check my question now, I have added in my sample JSON code.

Comment: even this is not valid JSON but you are having problem with POST so why you are adding GET request JSON

Comment: @iklinac sorry, I changed it to a POST request. How is it not a valid JSON?

Comment: you are missing commas http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf | https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @iklinac that was a copy and paste error, I have corrected it

Answer (score 0):

you should post like this:

```
{
    "username": "user_1",
    "email": "user1m@gmail.com",
    "password" : "testing1234"
}
```

Comment: That was a copy and paste error, I have corrected it.